# How to move a file using Putty? (mv: missing destination file operand)

Tags: unix, putty

I'm trying to move a file on a server to another folder:

```
mv /opsw/Customer/TEST/@/Server/TEST.test.test.com/files/Administrator/C/Temp
/TEST_validateserver.htm /opsw/Customer/TEST/@/Server/TEST.test.test.com/files/Administrator/C/
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
mv: missing destination file operand after `/opsw/Customer/TEST/@/Server/TEST.test.test.com/files/Administrator/C/Temp'
Try `mv --help' for more information.
bash: line 1: /TEST_validateserver.htm: No such file or directory
```

What's going on?

Comment: You're not "using Putty" to move the file, you're using Putty to get a console connection to a remote machine, where you're running a shell, from which you're running the `mv` command.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is a newline/space in between. Run this

```
mv /opsw/Customer/TEST/@/Server/TEST.test.test.com/files/Administrator/C/Temp/TEST_validateserver.htm /opsw/Customer/TEST/@/Server/TEST.test.test.com/files/Administrator/C/
```